# Find Keyword(s) in UsedRange - VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, find, expression

I am trying to look for a Keyword (e.g. Quantity, Qty, Qty., ... , etc) within range (in this case used range) but I am experiencing a problem; the search is slow because I am using `InStr` and `For each cell in UsedRange`

Method 1 (Slow):

```
Private Function GetQtyColFromBOQ(thisBOQ As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim QtyWord(5), QtyWordG, Delim As String
    Dim cl As Range

    If thisBOQ Is Nothing Then Set thisBOQ = ActiveSheet

    Delim = "|#|"

    QtyWord(0) = "Quantity"
    QtyWord(1) = "Qty"
    QtyWord(2) = "Qty."
    QtyWord(3) = "Qnty"
    QtyWord(4) = "Qnty."

    QtyWordG = Delim & Join(QtyWord, Delim)

    For Each cl In thisBOQ.UsedRange
        If InStr(1, QtyWordG, Delim & cl.Value & Delim, vbTextCompare) Then
            Set GetQtyColumnFromBOQ = cl ' function return
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Method 2 (Not working): No match found

```
Private Function GetQtyColFromBOQ(thisBOQ As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim QtyWord(5) As String

    If thisBOQ Is Nothing Then Set thisBOQ = ActiveSheet

    QtyWord(0) = "Quantity"
    QtyWord(1) = "Qty"
    QtyWord(2) = "Qty."
    QtyWord(3) = "Qnty"
    QtyWord(4) = "Qnty."


    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 4
      Set GetQtyColumnFromBOQ = thisBOQ.UsedRange.Find(QtyWord(i), LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Next i
End Function
```

What could possibly be wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second one, you have a few issues.  First, you've spelled the function name incorrectly when assigning it the result of `Find`.  Then, you'll need to use `xlPart` for your `LookAt` argument when looking for a match within a string.  Then, you'll need to exit the function, once a match has been found.  Also, you'll need to precede the argument's name with the keyword `Optional` so that the argument can be made optional.  Try the following...

```
Private Function GetQtyColFromBOQ(Optional thisBOQ As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim QtyWord(2) As String

    If thisBOQ Is Nothing Then Set thisBOQ = ActiveSheet

    QtyWord(0) = "Quantity"
    QtyWord(1) = "Qty"
    QtyWord(2) = "Qnty"


    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(QtyWord) To UBound(QtyWord)
      Set GetQtyColFromBOQ = thisBOQ.UsedRange.Find(QtyWord(i), LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
      If Not GetQtyColFromBOQ Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next i

    Set GetQtyColFromBOQ = Nothing
End Function
```

Note that both the size of the array `QtyWord` and the number of search terms have been adjusted, as per `YowE3K`'s comments.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I'll try to check what I have done wrong.

Comment: (@Tima - If this worked for you, you can flag as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows.)

Comment: `Dim QtyWord(5) As String` could be `Dim QtyWord(4) As String` - there's no use allocating a position for index 5 if it isn't going to be used.  And, if searching `xlPart`, there is no point searching for `"Qty."` if `"Qty"` wasn't found, or searching for `"Qnty."` if `"Qnty"` wasn't found.

Comment: The code has been amended as per YowE3k's comments.  It also has been amended to allow an optional argument.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use this form of the loop (part of the loop code not shown in this snippet)

```
Dim wrd As Variant

For Each wrd In Array("Quantity", "Qty", "Qty.", "Qnty", "Qnty.")

    Set GetQtyColFromBOQ = thisBOQ.UsedRange.Find(wrd, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    .
    .
Next wrd
```